# Intellij cant compile flex project

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flex4.5

Make error message :

defaults: unable to open './themes/Spark/spark.css'

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem in my environment.

- Create a Maven project for the project - see FlexMojos - http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/
- Import the Maven project to Intellij

The upside to this approach is that you get a build structure that is independent of IDEs, provides a good reference point for your builds, good for Continuous Integration - all the benefits of using Maven.

The downside is the complexity of using Maven.

Comment: Any chance for a comment for the reason for the downvote?   I can see that my solution is a very roundabout way of solving the problem but I don't see any other solutions forthcoming.